# Problemas ao gerar executável

Tags: python

Eu nunca me vi na necessidade de gerar um arquivo .EXE, pois meus programas eram testados em minha própria máquina, mas no entanto, agora eu preciso gerar um EXE para testar em outros computadores.

No meu programa eu importei as seguintes bibliotecas:

```
from pygame  import mixer # Load the required library
from pygame  import time #teste
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *

import tkinter.simpledialog
import tkinter.messagebox
```

Quando eu rodo o script no interpretador, o programa roda normalmente, mas quando eu vou executar o EXE e clico nos botões "Criar playlist" ou "Abrir Playlist", ele retorna um erro, falando que o nome simpledialog não foi definido no programa.

Eu já tentei adicionar:

```
name  = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Name", "Nome da Playlist")  
name  = simpledialog.askstring("Name", "Nome da Playlist")
```

Mas ainda não funciona, estou enviando uma print.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc ta usando o que pra empacotar o exe? Eu não vi seu import e não tenho conhecimento em GUI com Python, mas eu acho que pode ser que na hora de empacotar sua aplicação algum módulo tenha ficado de fora. Já tive problema parecido com uma aplicação minha empacotada com py2exe.

Comment: @HenriqueMarti - O problema estava na vai ável Name, eu declarava ela no interpretador como name, e dentro do entry eu usava Name. o interpretador passou, mas o EXE não abriu

Comment: Bom, então você já resolveu, ne? Acho que era uma boa você colocar uma resposta pra você mesmo explicando o problema e a solução. Isso vai ajudar mais gente. Abraço

Comment: @HenriqueMarti - Certo então, irei adicionar uma resposta